# How do you max out damage output for the climax hex in dark souls 2

Tags: dark-souls-2

So I am on the quest to make my climax spell hit the highest amount of damage. I was told dark sunset staff + 5 or 10, forgot, is the best staff for hex damage. I tried every hex and for some reason the dark sunset staff doesn't work with hexes. at all. If you know how to make the staff work with hexes, let me know. 
Anyway so I am using the black witch's staff + 9. So far I've been able to do up to 2,400 damage. However there is a video where someone does 3990 damage.

So what are the best items in the game to absolutely max out the climax damage?

Answer (score 2):

The thing about hexes is that it scales off both INT *and* FAITH. But the catch is it goes off the *lowest* of the two stats. So the best thing to do when using hexes is keep these two stats level.

As for equipment, and using hexes, most of the time you are better off using chimes (except when the hex specifically states it requires a staff). And the best chimes to use are either Caitha's Chime, or the Chime of Want.

While yes, the Dark Sunset staff can be used for casting hexes, it can only be used for hexes that specifically require a staff as a catalyst.